# Get the address from the transaction

Tags: transactions

I'm from Ukraine and do not know much English, sorry. For example first block https://blockchain.info/block/000000000019d6689c085ae165831e934ff763ae46a2a6c172b3f1b60a8ce26f, when miner confirm this block he get bonus (50 BTC). And he make transaction https://blockchain.info/ru/tx/4a5e1e4baab89f3a32518a88c31bc87f618f76673e2cc77ab2127b7afdeda33b, but in the first block be kept info about coinbase and script sig

```
Coin Base - 04ffff001d0104455468652054696d65732030332f4a616e2f32303039204368616e63656c6c6f72206f6e206272696e6b206f66207365636f6e64206261696c6f757420666f722062616e6b73

Script sig - 04678afdb0fe5548271967f1a67130b7105cd6a828e03909a67962e0ea1f61deb649f6bc3f4cef38c4f35504e51ec112de5c384df7ba0b8d578a4c702b6bf11d5f OP_CHECKSIG

And address 1A1zP1eP5QGefi2DMPTfTL5SLmv7DivfNa and hash for generate address 62e907b15cbf27d5425399ebf6f0fb50ebb88f18
```

where did you get the address?

EDIT

How get address or hash for generate adress from publicScriptSig

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initial Bitcoin transactions are slightly different from what we use today.

Addresses don't technically exist as far as the blockchain is concerned. They are simply a human-friendly representation of the underlying Bitcoin Scripts, that come with some properties like checksums to prevent typographical errors.

Original Bitcoin transactions were simply Pay-to-pubkey (P2PK), such as the one you see in the Coinbase above. In this, `04678afdb0fe5548271967f1a67130b7105cd6a828e03909a67962e0ea1f61deb649f6bc3f4cef38c4f35504e51ec112de5c384df7ba0b8d578a4c702b6bf11d5f` is the public key (note that this is the full public key, and not hashed).

Many coin explorers choose to treat this as a regular Bitcoin address, and perform the encoding steps outlined [here](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Technical_background_of_version_1_Bitcoin_addresses). You can use [this](https://iancoleman.io/bitcoin-key-compression/) tool to check the public key creates `1A1zP1eP5QGefi2DMPTfTL5SLmv7DivfNa` as an *uncompressed* address (compressed keys were not known at the time of the genesis block, they were discovered later).

Modern day addresses are either P2PKH Pay-to-pubkey-hash (this hash is `62e907b15cbf27d5425399ebf6f0fb50ebb88f18` for the above key), P2SH pay-to-script-hash (this is used for multisig, and P2SH wrapped segwit), and P2WPKH pay-to-witness-pubkey-hash and P2WPSH pay-to-witness-script-hash segwit addresses (these start with `bc1`).

However, on the raw blockchain, all you will see is the Bitcoin Script that the addresses are encoding. Addresses are a purely human addition on top of the underlying transaction standards.

Comment: Thank you, but you say P2PKH - hash from public key, but https://imgur.com/a/Tw7SJvM. How get P2PK-hash from public key?

Comment: You can follow the steps [here](https://en.bitcoin.it/w/index.php?title=Technical_background_of_version_1_Bitcoin_addresses&oldid=64130) to get the exact hash, looks like the current version of the wiki is missing the complete example